# Deployed Vercel App Local Time Incorrect?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I automatically toggle dark mode on my website when the time is before 8am and after 8pm (approximately).

Here the code snippet which accomplishes that:

```
const currentTime: number = new Date().getHours();
const isNightTime: boolean = 8 <= currentTime && currentTime <= 20 ? false : true;
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean>(isNightTime);
```

This works fine in NextJS development and production mode, but when I deploy it via Vercel, it turns on dark mode when it shouldn't.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.